# Possible to use default user picture in rewritten views field?

Tags: views

I have a view which displays fields and one of them is a rewritten field to display the user picture along with some other information. There is no issue if the user picture is uploaded, but if the user does not, this field does not show the default user picture. Is there anything I need to do to allow the default user image to display in this rewritten views field?

I tried unchecking the hide field if empty option under no results behaviour, but realised that since I already rewrote the field, this does not seem to apply, because my rewrite renders other fields that always have values in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use no result behavior option to show the default picture for the user's image.

Here is my screenshot :

[image]

If you want to combine two fields then you have to take two field firstly in view fields and shown their output in diffrent-2 field after that you can combine both fields in new field using rewrite option. The first two field output is hidden who's value you want to combine.

Comment: My problem is that the field will never be empty because it is already rewritten to have a field which always has a value so the no results text will never be displayed.

Comment: Take two fields separately in the view. and then add another one field( anyone ). Set the two fields value which you want to show. If empty then set their no result behavior and make them hide.
after that the third filed is your combination of two fields. The output of third filed  is rewritten.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Thank you for your patience. Marking this as the answer.